# How to only run previously failed tests with dotnet vstest

Tags: .net-core, vstest, vstest.console.exe

I have a test suite of over 10,000 tests and sometimes only want to rerun the tests, that failed on the previous run, using the `dotnet vstest` CLI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up using the following PowerShell command, to run only the previously failed tests again, based on the newest `trx` file in `.\TestResults\`:

`dotnet vstest '.\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\MyTests.dll' /Logger:trx /Tests:"$((Select-Xml -Path (gci '.\TestResults\' | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1).FullName -XPath "//ns:UnitTestResult[@outcome='Failed']/@testName" -Namespace @{"ns"="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010"}).Node.Value | % {$_ -replace '^My\.Long\.And\.Tedious\.Namespace\.', ''} | % {$_ -replace '^(.*?)\(.*$','$1'} | Join-String -Separator ','))"`

Beware, that there is a character limit on the maximum command line length, that can easily be hit when many tests have previously failed.
Use the `% {$_ -replace '^My\.Long\.And\.Tedious\.Namespace\.', ''}` part, to get rid of namespace prefixes, if you can.

Comment: !!! You just saved me a lot of time !!! The `NET5` command for `xUnit` will look slightly different, for example: ...

Comment: ```dotnet test .\MyUnitTests\bin\Debug\net5.0\MyUnitTests.dll --logger "trx;LogFileName=MyUnitTests_01.xml" --results-directory .\TestResults --logger "console;verbosity=minimal" --filter ("DisplayName~" + ((Select-Xml -Path .\TestResults\MyUnitTests.xml -XPath "//ns:UnitTestResult[@outcome='Failed']/@testName" -Namespace @{"ns"="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010"}).Node.Value | % {$_ -replace '^MyUnitTests\.', ''} | % {$_ -replace '^(.*?)\(.*$','$1'} | Join-String -Separator ' | DisplayName~'))```