# How can I get my Dotnet Test to rerun failed tests

Tags: .net, azure-pipelines, browserstack

I am using C#. I am using Azure Pipelines and BrowserStack. I know how to get the Pipelines to rerun the task but I want to only run the failed tests for a second time right after the initial failures. Is this possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a custom task in pipeline and dotnet test command line. It needs a bit of hack since dontnet test does not provide a command line parameter to run only the failed tests. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57980972/how-to-only-run-previously-failed-tests-with-dotnet-vstest) can help you build the command to be run from the custom task.

Also, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/integrate-build-task?view=azure-devops) demonstrates building custom task in Azure pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please update the Browserstack azure plugin and also try the solution suggested above
https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-test-rerun

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).